# Linq query does not return the same data that SQL query does

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I am getting a list using:

```
var recommend1 = db.Recommendation
    .Where(c => c.Comments != "" && 
                c.Comments != null && 
                c.Visit.ClinicId == 5)
    .Select(c => c.VisitId)
    .ToList();
```

This returns 0.  However, when I test it as a SQL using the following:

```
SELECT dbo.Visit.VisitId
FROM   dbo.Recommendation 
    INNER JOIN dbo.Visit ON dbo.Recommendation.VisitId = dbo.Visit.VisitId
WHERE  
    (dbo.Visit.ClinicId = '5') AND 
    (dbo.Recommendation.Comments = '') OR
    (dbo.Recommendation.Comments IS NULL)
```

It returns 3!!  Column Comments is non-nullable nvarchar(MAX).

Why the results are not the same?

Comment: The where clauses are different.  In the Linq: `c.Comments != ""` and in the SQL `Comments = ''`

Comment: If `Comments` is `NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL`, why exactly are you checking against null?

Comment: @AmyB That's correct. Voting to close as typo

Comment: note that the syntax "Visit.ClinicId = '5'" suggests that the db column is (n)varchar, while your linq query suggests in your model it is a long/integer. You should work on matching up model and database schema as well as brush up on some LINQ (especially in this case L2SQL) knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var recommend1 = db.Recommendation.Where(c => c.Comments != "" || c.Comments != null)
                                  .Where(c => c.Visit.ClinicId == 5)
                                  .Select(c => c.VisitId)
                                  .ToList();

// is not the same as

WHERE(dbo.Visit.ClinicId = '5') 
   AND(dbo.Recommendation.Comments = '') OR (dbo.Recommendation.Comments IS NULL)
```

You are first instructing for all results where comments or not null or empty, your sql statement is asking for ones which are

If you're trying to emulate the SQL statement, change your linq query to this.

```
var recommend1 = db.Recommendation.Where(c => c.Comments == "" || c.Comments == null)
                                  .Where(c => c.Visit.ClinicId == 5)
                                  .Select(c => c.VisitId)
                                  .ToList();
```